# Реклама Unity ads на андроиде не показывается

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Я разрабатываю игру для андроид. Дошло дело до встраивания рекламы.
Использую Rewarded ads. В редакторе Unity реклама показывается и все работает хорошо.
При сборке apk и установке на андроид никаких ошибок. Но на андроид-устройстве рекламы нету.

Инициализация рекламы

```
public void InitializeAds()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize(data.gameId, data.testMode);
}
public void OnInitializationComplete()
{
    Debug.Log("Ads initialization complete");
}

public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
{
    Debug.Log("Ads initialization failed");
}
```

Реклама с вознаграждением:

```
public class RewardedAds : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsShowListener, IUnityAdsLoadListener
{
    public static RewardedAds S;
    private string rewardedAd = "Rewarded_Android";

    void Awake()
    {
        S = this;
        Advertisement.Load(rewardedAd, this);
    }

    public void loadAd()
    {
        Advertisement.Load(rewardedAd, this);
    }
    public void showAd()
    {
        Advertisement.Show(rewardedAd, this);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string placementId)
    {
        Debug.Log("rewardedAd loaded");
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string placementId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("rewardedAd failed to load");
    }


    public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string placementId){}

    public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string placementId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
    {
        if (placementId.Equals(rewardedAd) && showCompletionState.Equals(UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED))
        {
            //добавляю монетки

            Advertisement.Load(rewardedAd, this);
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string placementId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message){}

    public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string placementId){}
}
```

Вот так вызываю, для показа:

```
RewardedAds.S.showAd();
```

Получаю вот такую тестовую рекламу, но только в unity редакторе. На андроиде нету.

[image: Тестовая реклама от Unity Ads]

Еще вспомнил, что сразу после добавления рекламы, в Build settings было такое сообщение:

[image: сообщение]

Но после некоторого времени оно пропало.
Это мой личный проект, я его создавал, создавал организацию. В Unity DashBoard написано, что я Owner. Поэтому мало вероятно, что в этом дело.

Сначала попробовал встроить Google AdMob, но там совсем все плохо.

Любая помощь! Спасибо!

Comment: Выкладывате вопрос с кодом всегда, имейте такую привычку на данном ресурсе, Вам смогут помочь быстрее, и вообще смогут помочь! Жду как получу больше информации, то как Вы внедрили рекламу и то как вы ее используете, и то где вы ее используете в коде

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Код добавил!

Answer (score 0):

Решено! В другом месте подсказали, что нужно было галочку поставить вот здесь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]